# (Vue.js) "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

I am trying to display data stored in a Firebase remote database in a Vue 3 webpage with a table however when I route to the display page I return the error. This is what my code looks like.

This is the HTML that displays the table:

```
<template>
<section v-if="!this.results.length">
No data to show
</section>
<section v-else>
<table class="table">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th scope="col">View</th>
  <th scope="col">Identification</th>
  <th scope="col">Name</th>
  <th scope="col">Surname</th>
  <th scope="col">Email</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr v-for="res in results" :key="res.id">
<!-- <td><button class="btn btn-primary">View</button></td> -->
<td>{{res.idCard}}</td>
<td>{{res.name}}</td>
<td>{{res.surname}}</td>
<td>{{res.email}}</td>
<!-- <td><button class='btn btn-primary'>Update</button></td> -->
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</section>
</template>
```

And this is the Javascript. Here it is supposed to fetch the data from the firebase and push it into the results[] array.

```
<script>
export default {
data(){
return{
  results: []
  };
 },

  methods:{
async getData(){
  console.log("Getting data");
  try{
  const response = await fetch("https://fir-example-56e32-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/contact.json",{
    method: 'GET'
  }) //the below will parse the data thats part of the response if it is in json format; returns a promise
    const responseData = await response.json();
    if(!response.ok){
          console.log("Something went wrong") 
    }
    const results = [];
    for (const id in responseData){
      results.push({
        id:id,
        idCard: responseData[id].idCard,
        name: responseData[id].name,
        surname: responseData[id].surname,
        email: responseData[id].email,
      });  
      this.results = results;
    }
  }catch(error){
    console.log(error);
  }
 },
  },
//when component is fully initialised call method
  mounted(){
  this.getData();
}
}
</script>
```

[the form in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVkRh.png)

[what it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpsD0.png)

Comment: remove the `this.` in `<section v-if="!this.results.length">` and re-read vue documentation - you never need to use `this` in markup

Comment: Unrelated but nevertheless... Parsing the response (`await response.json()`) and only then checking if the response is valid (`response.ok`) is the wrong order.

Comment: @Andreas - one would also stop processing (i.e. return in the if condition) if response was not "ok" - rather than log the error and carry on as if everything went ok :p

Comment: Thank you, Jaromanda. Removing .this did indeed work

Comment: Do you get any error? Another question: any specific reason for not using the Firebase JavaScript SDK?